# Выборка по группам из SQL таблицы

Tags: mysql

Добрый день! Нужна ваша помощь! Предположим у меня есть таблица следующего вида:

```
----------------------
| user_id | group_id |
|--------------------|
|    1    |     2    |
|    1    |     3    |
|    1    |     4    |
|    2    |     3    |
|    2    |     5    |
|    3    |     2    |
|    3    |     3    |
----------------------
```

Мне необходимо выбрать все user_id у которых group_id равен 2 и 3.одновременно. Т.е под этот критерий попадают записи с user_id = 1 и 3.
Как это можно сделать 1 SQL запросом? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select user_id
from test
where group_id in (2, 3)      -- номера групп
group by user_id
having count(group_id) = 2;   -- количество искомых групп
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e23b3/5

Comment: А если есть дубликаты строк? Тогда

     select user_id from test where group_id = 2 and user_id in 
       (select user_id from test where group_id = 3)

Comment: Если дубликаты строк, то автор плохо спроектировал таблицу. Мой модуль телепатии подсказывает мне, что в этой таблице отображается принадлежность пользователей группам. Ситуация, в которой пользователь входит в одну группу дважды ошибочна, её нужно исключить, повесив составной primary key `(user_id, group_id)`.

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Я как-то не додумался до такого. Привык к простым запросам :)
Да, дубликатов строк в таблице нет и быть не должно.

Comment: @fori1ton не primary, а просто unique